# Remove the password on several RAR files at once

Tags: windows, gratis, batch, rar

I have several RAR files with the same password. I am looking for a gratis program that can remove the password on all these RAR files at once. I use Windows 10.

In WinRAR, I can [use](https://superuser.com/a/381905/116475):

> `Tools > Convert Archives > Compression > General > Set Password >` then click ok and save.

but I need to batch process and WinRaR isn't free.

Answer (score 1):

One can use [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) (gratis).

- Step 1: uncompress all RAR archives at once, via right-click in explorer.exe.
- Step 2: re-archive all folders at once (1 folder per archive file) with [this command](https://superuser.com/a/1763073/116475), in windows command prompt:
  `for /D %d in (*.*) do 7z a -tzip "%d.7z" "%d"`